TypeScript Error: Type 'HotelType[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'HotelType'
I'm encountering a type error in my React TypeScript application when trying to pass a hotel object to a form component. The error message is as follows:

Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HotelType'.ts(2322) ManageHotelForm.tsx(27, 5): The expected type comes from property 'hotel' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'

These are all the relevant parts of the code:
// page.tsx

    const EditHotel = () => {
        const {hotelId} = useParams();
        const {data:hotel} = useQuery("fetchHotelById", ()=> apiClient.fetchHotelById(hotelId || ""),{ enabled: !!hotelId})
      return <ManageHotelForm hotel={hotel} />
    }

// HotelType.tsx

    export type HotelType = {
        _id: string;
        userId: string;
        name: string;
        city: string;
        country: string
        description: string;
        type: string;
        adultCount: number;
        childCount: number;
        facilities: string[];
        pricePerNight: number;
        starRating: number;
        imageURLs: string[];
        lastUpdated: Date;
    
    }

//ManageHotelForm.tsx

    type Props = {
        onSave: (hotelFormData: FormData)=> void
        isLoading: boolean,
        hotel: HotelType,
    }
    
    const ManageHotelForm = ({onSave,isLoading,hotel}: Props) => {
        const formMethods = useForm<HotelFormData>()
    
        const {handleSubmit,reset} = formMethods; 
        useEffect(()=>{
            reset(hotel);
        },[hotel,reset]);


//fetchHotelById

    export const fetchHotelById = async (hotelId: string): Promise<HotelType[]> => {
        const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/api/my-hotels/${hotelId}`, {
            credentials: "include"
        })
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Error fetching hotels');
        }
    
        return response.json();
    }

//Backend route

    router.get('/:id',verifyToken, async (req:Request,res:Response)=>{
        const id = req.params.id.toString();
        try {
            const hotel = await Hotel.findOne({
                _id: id,
                userId: req.userId,
            });
            res.json(hotel);
        } catch (error) {   
            res.status(500).json({message: "Error fetching hotels"})
        }
    })

The code is working as expected yet the hotel={hotel} in the Page.tsx is throwing an error. I'm new to Typescript, so I have yet to know how to make it happy.

const {data:hotel} = // ...

According to fetchHotelById, hotel will be an array of HotelType, once it's loaded. And since there's a period of time when it has not yet been loaded, hotel could also be undefined.
type Props = {
    onSave: (hotelFormData: FormData)=> void
    isLoading: boolean,
    hotel: HotelType,
}

But the props for ManageHotelForm say it can only take HotelType. It cannot work with an array, nor with undefined.
If ManageHotelForm requires an individual hotel, make sure to pass one in. For example:
if (!hotel) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
} else {
  return (
    <>
      {hotel.map(val => (
         <ManageHotelForm hotel={val} />
       )}
    </>
  )
}

On the other hand if ManageHotelForm works just fine with an array or undefined, change the type on its props:
type Props = {
    onSave: (hotelFormData: FormData)=> void
    isLoading: boolean,
    hotel: HotelType[] | undefined,
}

Ps, based on the name, the type on fetchHotelById may be wrong. Ie, it may return just a single hotel, not an array of them. If so, change its return type to Promise<HotelType>.
